# Redirect BuddyPress pages by Roles

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to redirect users who are neither sea_member or administrator to a signup page when they hit Buddypress/BBPress pages. Here's the code I'm struggling with:

```
function kleo_page_template_redirect()
{
    if( 
        ( ( ! current_user_can('sea_member') || ! current_user_can('administrator') ) ) &&
        ( ( ! bp_is_blog_page() && ! bp_is_activation_page() && ! bp_is_register_page() ) || is_bbpress() )
    )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/become-a-member/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'kleo_page_template_redirect' );
```

If I remove the second role (administrator) then the function works fine for role sea_member. Administrator is always redirected which is what the problem is.

Please help with this, I'm not a coder :(

Comment: '||' means 'OR', try using '&&' instead.

Comment: I used OR because users will have either role, not both.